# SQL Database design question

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design

I have a task to design a SQL database that will record values for the company's commodity products (sku numbers). The company has 7600 unique product items that need to be tracked, and each product will have approximately 200 values over the period of a year (one value per product per day, over the period of a year).

My first guess is that the sku numbers go top to bottom (each sku has a row) and each date is a column.

The data will be used to view in chart / graph format and additional calculations will be displayed against those (such as percentage profit margin etc)

My question is:
- is this layout advisable?
- do I have to be cautious of anything, if this type of data goes back about 15 yrs (each table will represent a year)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a table for your products, and a table for the historical values.  Maybe create an index for the historical values based on date if you plan to select for specific time periods.

```
create table products (
 id number primary key,
 sku number,
 name text,
 desc text);

create table values (
 id number primary key,
 product_id number,
 timestamp date,
 value number,
 foreign key fk_prod_price product_id on product.id);

create index idx_price on values.timestamp;
```

NOTE: not actual sql, you will have to write your own

Comment: by creating the index, and seperate tables, that would make it faster to display on screen... thats a huge plus... thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

It better to have 3 columns only - instead of many as you are suggesting:

```
sku    date         value
-------------------------
1      2011-01-01   10
1      2011-01-02   12
2      2011-01-01   5
```

This way you can easily add another column if you want to record something else about a given product per date.

Comment: I am working on your suggestion, but if I use your idea, I will need 200 x 7600 rows. That will make for a REALLY long table.

Comment: That's nothing, I work with tables with more than 50M rows. Tables are usually way much longer than wider. That's the whole point of the traditional databases.

Answer (score 1):

If you do like @fiver wrote, you don't have to have a table for each year either. Everything in one table. And add indexes  on sku/date for faster searching